Game theory one shot deviation principle
Consider a variant of the alternative offers bargaining game studied
in class. Two players are bargaining over the split of a pie of total
size/value 1; each player likes as big a share as he can get. In each
round, a player can be a proposer or a proposee (i.e. someone to whom
a proposal is made). Every round, player 1 gets to be the proposer
with probability π, and correspondingly, 2 gets to be the proposer
with probability 1 − π. The proposer offers a split of the pie. If the
proposee accepts the offer then the pie is split as per the offer and the
game ends. If the offer is not accepted the game proceeds to the next
round. Each player has a discount factor δ ∈ (0, 1).
Using the one shot deviation principle, find the sub-game perfect
Nash equilibrium of the game. Restrict your attention to stationery
strategies, wherein in each round a player offers the same split if he is
the proposer, and uses the same accept/reject rule if he is the proposee.

"Consider a variant of the alternative offers bargaining game studied in class." Why would you include this sentence...?
